# Is there error in this code for a table?

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table using [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com) using the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\def\@setcopyright{}
\def\serieslogo@{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\label{T1} 
\begin{tabular}{|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|}              
\hline 
$r/r_b$ & $\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}pr_b^2$ & $\frac{8\pi G}{c^2}\rho r_b^2$ & $\Big (    \frac{p}{\rho c^2} \Big )$ & $\frac{1}{c^2}\Big(\frac{dp}{d\rho}\Big)$ & $Z$ & $E\times r_b^2$ \\ \hline
0 & 0.095358 & 1.753927 & 0.054368 & 0.141513 & 0.502225 & 0 \\ \hline
0.1 & 0.093012 & 1.741188 & 0.053419 & 0.140512 & 0.499676 & 0.0000044\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}​
```

When I run the code it returns 7 errors, although the table is made perfectly. What is the cause of these harmless errors and how do I remove them. A second question I wish to ask is how do I give a title to the table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to use either `l`, `r`, or `c` for your `tabular` column specifiers, not `1`, unless you make this a `\newcolumntype{1}{<col spec>}` using [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array). You can place a heading as normal text just before the `tabular`, or insert it as part of the table using a `\multicolumn{7}{c}{<heading>} \\` statement:

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{This is a heading}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}              
\hline 
$r/r_b$ & $\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}pr_b^2$ & $\frac{8\pi G}{c^2}\rho r_b^2$ & $\Big (    \frac{p}{\rho c^2} \Big )$ & $\frac{1}{c^2}\Big(\frac{dp}{d\rho}\Big)$ & $Z$ & $E\times r_b^2$ \\ \hline
0 & 0.095358 & 1.753927 & 0.054368 & 0.141513 & 0.502225 & 0 \\ \hline
0.1 & 0.093012 & 1.741188 & 0.053419 & 0.140512 & 0.499676 & 0.0000044\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

As Martin and Werner said, 1 is not a column format specifier, you could use `l` instead. The seven 1s result in the seven errors.

Regarding your second question: to get a title for the table, use `\caption{title}`. For this it's recommendable to use a `table` environment, see below.

Some recommendations:

- Instead of writing the same format seven times, you could load the `array` package and say

  ```
  \begin{tabular}{|*7{l|}}
  ```
- You could raise `\arraystretch` to get a better vertical spacing.
- It could be nicer to avoid vertical rules, just using horizontal rules.
- The `booktabs` package provides nice rules.
- Don't use `\label` without `\caption` before.
- Consider using a floating environment such as `table` for good placement done by LaTeX.
- Perhaps center the heading cells using `\multicolum{1}{c}{...}`.

[image: table example]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\def\@setcopyright{}
\def\serieslogo@{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{First table}
\label{T1}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\begin{tabular}{*7l}
\toprule[1.5pt]
  $r/r_b$ & $\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}pr_b^2$ & $\frac{8\pi G}{c^2}\rho r_b^2$ &
    $\Big (    \frac{p}{\rho c^2} \Big )$ &
    $\frac{1}{c^2}\Big(\frac{dp}{d\rho}\Big)$ & $Z$ & $E\times r_b^2$ \\
\midrule
  0 & 0.095358 & 1.753927 & 0.054368 & 0.141513 & 0.502225 & 0 \\
  0.1 & 0.093012 & 1.741188 & 0.053419 & 0.140512 & 0.499676 & 0.0000044\\ 
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}​
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you use a `1` (one) not a `l` (lowercase L) as the columns specification:

This means:

```
\begin{tabular}{|1|1|1|1|1|1|1|}
```

should be:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
```

This might be difficult to separate in your used font.